# JCache CacheResult - creating caches with the default name

Tags: java, spring, jcache

I'm using JCache annotations with Spring and EhCache. If I use @CacheResult on a method without specifying the cache name (or a @CacheDefaults on the class), then the default cache name resolves to the fully qualified method name. However such a cache is not found, unless explicitly created using the CacheManager. This may be manageable for a few such cache-enabled methods, but not if I have to create 50 different caches manually.

Is there a way to tell Spring (or any JCache implementer) to automatically create caches with the default name, if not found? This would allow me to use @CacheResult on any method without having to go update the cache configuration every time.

Comment: It's 2024 and I still have this issue. Using EhCache, the caches are created automatically. Moving to redis or hazelcast, I get the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named...

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to tell Spring (or any JCache implementer) to automatically create caches with the default name, if not found?

This problem is covered in [cache2k](https://cache2k.org/). You can configure cache2k to use a default configuration, if the requested cache name is not known.

Here is an example XML configuration for this scenario, which is placed at `/cache2k.xml` in the class path:

```
<cache2k xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
         xmlns='https://cache2k.org/schema/v1.x'
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://cache2k.org/schema/v1.x https://cache2k.org/schema/cache2k-core-v1.x.xsd">
  <version>1.0</version>
  <ignoreMissingCacheConfiguration>true</ignoreMissingCacheConfiguration>
  <defaults>
    <!-- default settings for every cache -->
    <cache>
      <entryCapacity>100_000</entryCapacity>
      <expireAfterWrite>5m</expireAfterWrite>
    </cache>
  </defaults>
  <templates>
    <cache>
      <name>shortExpiry</name>
      <expireAfterWrite>5m</expireAfterWrite>
    </cache>
    <cache>
      <name>lessResilient</name>
      <resilienceDuration>1m</resilienceDuration>
    </cache>
  </templates>
  <caches>
    <cache>
      <name>products</name>
      <entryCapacity>10_000</entryCapacity>
      <include>shortExpiry,lessResilient</include>
    </cache>
    <cache>
      <name>users</name>
      <entryCapacity>1000</entryCapacity>
      <include>shortExpiry</include>
    </cache>
  </caches>
</cache2k>
```

By default, according to this configuration, a cache without a specific configuration entry will get 100K entry limit and 5 minutes expiry. The configuration may be suitable for the trails in production. Later on, you, or a system operator, can check what caches are existing and their performance via JMX and then add a more specific cache configuration as soon as there is need. If you have many caches, the configuration has a template mechanism to avoid repetition.

It may happen that caches need a specific configuration upfront and some don't. I suggest separating them into different cache managers.

If you need an in process cache, cache2k is a a good alternative to EHCache. It is way faster and more memory efficient.

You can use cache2k via JCache, however there is also direct Spring framework support. See the [User Guide Spring Framework Section](https://cache2k.org/docs/latest/user-guide.html#spring) for details.

I am the author of cache2k and not a heavy Spring user at the moment, however, I am happy to help if there are any issues.